# How can multiple Bar charts be stacked together in Spotfire, without crossing their data?

Tags: visualization, spotfire

I am trying to display the results of a multiple choice question here, in a simple yes/no style manner, so as to have each question results answered side by side.
Example with this sample dataset:

```
A   apples  yes butter
B   bananas yes peanut
C   bananas yes butter
D   apples  yes peanut
E   apples  no  butter
F   bananas no  peanut
G   apples  yes peanut
H   apples  no  peanut
I   bananas yes butter
J   apples  no  peanut
K   bananas yes peanut
L   apples  no  butter
M   apples  yes peanut
N   bananas yes butter
O   apples  no  butter
P   bananas yes butter
Q   bananas no  butter
R   apples  yes butter
S   bananas yes peanut
T   apples  no  butter
```

[done on paint, not exactly ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr7nc.jpg)

This means having one bar per possible answer (column), which height is determined by the count of its respondents.

The problem I encountered is that Spotfire **automatically crosses data** for multiple columns, so that for 3 questions (Yes/No) I do not end up with *3 bar charts* as I would like, but *8 bar charts* which correspond to 8 possible combinations, and their counts (yes/yes/no, no/yes/no, etc).
[this is what you get basically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z0io.jpg)

Is there a way to simply display column line counts without crossing data?

Comment: usually i'm against images, but I think we need to see what you are seeing to understand this. Also a sample dataset would be nice.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want to Nest the columns, because they're unrelated, but if you put the questions on different graphs, the counts won't auto-size to the same numbers and it will be misleading.

If you're pulling from a database, you'll probably just want to pivot your data so all the questions are in the same column, and then Spotfire can make one bar per question.

Comment: Exactly. I am looking for a nicer way than creating a new pivot table, because most visualizations don't allow cross-table data to be displayed

Comment: sometimes the best way is to just pivot/unpivot your data. if you go this route, I suggest to **Add Data Table** and then choose **From current analysis...** so that you don't have a separate information link. that said, have you looked into trellis settings?

Comment: also, if you don't need to use the Marking feature, you can put an expression on your Y axis like `UniqueCount(If([answer] = "bananas", [ID]))`. Marking will not work, however, because technically this expression selects all data.